# Nuclear binding energy and natural radioactive decay

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, binding-energy

I have just started to learn about nuclear binding energy. While I believe I understand the concept well, there is one thing I do not still fully grasp.

I understand that the nuclear binding energy reflects the energy required to remove nucleons from the nucleus. Also, I get the fact that with larger atoms beyond iron, the repulsive force becomes greater, and so the atom becomes more unstable and, therefore, potentially radioactive.

It therefore makes sense to me that in, for instance, a fission reactor, firing a neutron at a uranium atom could intiate a nuclear reaction as it doesn't take that much effort to make uranium reach an excited state. However, where exactly does the energy come from which initiates *natural* radioactive decay? Say for instance when uranium somewhere in nature emits an alpha particle. Surely, some binding energy must be overcome in order for the particle to become emitted, right? So where does this energy come from when we do not have neutrons to fire at it?

If someone can explain this to me, then I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Alpha decay can be modeled as tunneling of the alpha out of the nucleus. Since there is a lower-energy state with the alpha out at infinity, it can occur.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling

Comment: Nuclei don't necessarily need to be large to be radioactive. Consider tritium.

Comment: The neutron does not need to bring energy to obtain a fission on 235U: the reaction begins with a capture of the neutron (capture all the more effective as the neutron is slow) by 235U, and then, it is unstable 236U that may fission (or not fission).

Comment: @JonCuster: Thank you very much! I wasn't familiar with the concept of tunnelling, but after reading your link, I now understand why natural radioactive decay may occur despite the binding energy.

Comment: @JeanJacques: Yes, my formulation was maybe not the best. I understand that the capture of the neturon primarily serves to make the atom unstable.

Comment: @JeanJacques - but for 238U the neutron does need to bring in ~1MeV to lead to fission. ENDF has the relevant cross sections vs energy.